# How to integrate Watson Studio python notebook with an IAE Spark?

Tags: pyspark, ibm-cloud, watson-studio, analytics-engine

I have an IBM Analytics Engine (IAE) instance, added it to my Watson Studio project as an associated service and created an Environment based on it.
Then, I created a python notebook and set its environment to the abovementioned.

I ran a simple pyspark script in the notebook and noticed that it uses a local instance instead of the IAE.

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
spark
```

output:

```
SparkSession - in-memory
SparkContext

Spark UI
Version
v2.4.5
Master
local[*]
AppName
pyspark-shell
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing nothing wrong. Your code gets sent to IAE for execution. So it is running locally in your IAE instance.